# How to use 'extract-text-plugin' in my webpack setup

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

I've been attempting to understand "production mode" in webpack. From what I gether now in webpack 2 you can run `webpack -p` but that doesn't seem as feature rich.
My setup I carried over from Webpack 1 is like so:

```
var config = {
context: __dirname + '/app',
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        moment: "moment"
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
}
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.output.path = __dirname + '/dist';
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
    config.plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"));
    config.module.loaders({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        })
    })
}

module.exports = config;
```

What I really want to so is use the `extract-text-plugin` in production mode, I have attempted the following:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.output.path = __dirname + '/dist';
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
    config.plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"));
    config.module.loaders({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        })
    })
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
config.loaders({
           ^
TypeError: config.loaders is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.module.loaders` is an array, so you would need to push just as you did with the plugins. But then you would end up with two loader configurations for `.scss`, which is clearly not what you desire. Instead you could define a variable which you pass to the config, like so:

```
// Default SCSS loader
var scssLoader = 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Overwrite it with the extract-text loader
  scssLoader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
  })
}
```

And then the `.scss` rule in your config would become:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: scssLoader,
  exclude: /node_modules/
},
```